How to make a disabled QLabel (or any image basically) retain color?
If I have a QLabel with a pixmap, and the QLabel is disabled, the pixmap will be automatically converted to grayscale.
Is there a way to avoid it?
I have a large GUI with lots of elements. I want to set it to disabled, but have one image inside it still showing some color.
The QLabel in question is itself enabled, but it does not matter, as the parent widget is disabled.
I tried removing the color effects with a stylesheet, but it did not work:
setStyleSheet("QLabel { color: none; } QLabel:disabled { background: none; color: none; opacity: 1.0; }");

The following don't work either in the stylesheet:
color: none !important;
color: unset !important;

I also tried removing the element's GraphicsEffect, but that did not work either.
The element in question is deeply embedded in a complex and resizable layout, so having it outside the parent widget and floating over it would be extremely complicated.

Either do the painting by yourself or use a proxy style and reimplement generatedIconPixmap() to not return a grayscaled pixmap

The only other alternative would be to use a QGraphicsView with hidden scrollbars and a QGraphicsPixmapItem, but properly implementing it won't be as effective as doing what suggested by chehrlic. Note that the stylesheet attempts you did are irrelevant, because colors and background are ineffective on the pixmap: the color only has meaning for the text, and the pixmap is drawn above the possible background.

In the first place, what do you disable a QLabel for? There is no way to interact with them even when enabled, is there?

@Atmo : I'm not disabling the QLabel. I'm disabling almost the entire UI (except for a reconnect interface), when connection is lost, and I would like for that QLabel to not be disabled only so that it retains color.

As you clarified in comments, what you are trying to do is to disable "almost the entire UI"; by disabling a widget, you also disable all its children, including the QLabels you would like to keep colored.
Instead of disabling/enabling the entire window/widget, I would go around this problem with a separate method to disable every descendent of it, but ignore the QLabel.
As a bonus, you can:

Apply a filter on the type of objects you want to disable.
Change the edit trigger of item views instead of disabling them, so that the scrollbars stay active (if that is what you want, otherwise disable them like the rest).

Here is a quick snippet of such method:
void setEnabled_descendents(
    bool enable,
    bool lineEdit   = true,
    bool textEdit   = true,
    bool checkbox   = true,
    bool radio      = true,
    bool combo      = true,
    bool pushButton = true,
    bool itemView   = true
) {
    if (lineEdit) {
        for (auto wLineEdit : findChildren<QLineEdit*>())
            wLineEdit->setEnabled(enable);
    }
    if (textEdit) {
        for (auto wTextEdit : findChildren<QTextEdit*>())
            wTextEdit->setEnabled(enable);
        for (auto wTextEdit : findChildren<QPlainTextEdit*>())
            wTextEdit->setEnabled(enable);
    }
    if (checkbox) {
        for (auto wCheck : findChildren<QCheckBox*>())
            wCheck->setEnabled(enable);
    }
    if (radio) {
        for (auto wRadio : findChildren<QRadioButton*>())
            wRadio->setEnabled(enable);
    }
    if (combo) {
        for (auto wCombo : findChildren<QComboBox*>())
            wCombo->setEnabled(enable);
    }
    if (pushButton) {
        for (auto wButton : findChildren<QPushButton*>())
            wButton->setEnabled(enable);
    }
    if (itemView) {
        QAbstractItemView::EditTriggers trigger = QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers;
        if (enable)
            trigger = QAbstractItemView::SelectedClicked |
                      QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked   |
                      QAbstractItemView::EditKeyPressed;
        for (auto wview : findChildren<QAbstractItemView*>())
            wview->setEditTriggers(trigger);
    }
}

If subclassing your widget class to add this method is a problem for you, the solution can easily be converted to a function, taking the widget to disable as one of its parameters.

I thought about this possibility, but it's quite problematic. Most importantly, it will also enable widgets that have been explicitly disabled. One may consider checking the WA_ForceDisabled attribute, but properly implementing it would still be difficult: what if the program needs to call setEnabled() on a specific widget, which should eventually retain its disabled state if the parent is disabled as well? Or what if new widgets are added in the meantime? A similar conceptual issue also exists for item views, which completely overwrites existing triggers that cannot be restored back.

Besides, disabled scroll areas are expected to be completely disabled (otherwise they would be inconsistent with the expected behavior), so there's no point in changing the edit triggers.Note that I believe you meant to use setEnabled(enable) in all calls (you only did it for wLineEdit). In any case, I'm afraid that this is not an acceptable approach, because doing it appropriately would require a much more complex implementation that could result in more issues than benefits. Setting a proxy style on the label, or using QPicture as in my proposal, are much simpler and safer solutions.

I do not see anything you point as an issue: 1. disabling a widget means disabling its children, a brute force approach is appropriate; 2. managing disabled parents is neither solved not worsend with this solution; 3. Adding new children to a widget is an extremely rare case and even so, managing their state only requires 1 more line of code; 4. changing the edit trigger for views is a choice, and that makes the solution more flexible than disabling them entirely, but OP can edit the code to do just that if they want (and they may have to change the triggers they want to enable).

Sorry, but I cannot agree. 1. such a "brute force" approach completely disregards the original state that may be eventually explicitly set on children: calling setEnabled(true) on them from an external function would completely ignore any state set by another aspect that assumes that the actual state is also inherited by the parent; 2. Qt provides automatic inheritance of enabled states which can cause conflicts difficult to solve when trying to change the specific widget state from a different context; 3. adding new children is not an "extremely rare case", it's something that could »

» be required at any time: we cannot assume the OP doesn't change the widget structure, they mention network management, what if they have some logging scroll area that adds widgets on "ping" timeouts? Such additions would certainly not require only one more line of code, especially if they're done in other classes; 4. changing the edit triggers is a choice that requires very thoughful considerations: what if the UI contains many item views, each one with their own edit triggers? Selectively disabling widgets is a possibility, but not an very effective one, because it doesn't really solve »

» the actual problem and, instead, may create new ones: the issue is with the appearance of one widget class, therefore that is what should be addressed and fixed.

QLabel internally uses drawItemPixmap() when drawing its pixmap, but, before that, it also calls generatedIconPixmap() in case the widget is disabled (which also includes the possibility of inherited disabled states caused by any parent).
As written in the comments, one possibility could be to create a custom QProxyStyle that overrides generatedIconPixmap() and simply returns the given pixmap without altering it, then set that style specifically to the label.
Alternatively, you may also subclass QLabel and override paintEvent() to draw the pixmap on your own (or by installing an event filter).
There is also the alternative of using QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsPixmapItem, but it may be a bit difficult to do it properly, because the implementation should consider both sizeHint() and minimumSizeHint().
There is a further option, though.
QLabel allows using QPicture, which is a sort of "QPainter recorder". The solution is then to create a QPicture with the required pixmap, and call setPicture() instead.
Since QLabel has no way to alter the behavior of QPicture, it always draws it in the same way, even if the widget is disabled.
I'm not a C++ developer, so I won't try to write in that language, but the following example in Python should be clear enough:
pixmap = self.ui.label.pixmap()
if not pixmap.isNull():
    pic = QPicture()
    qp = QPainter(pic)
    qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
    qp.end()
    self.ui.label.setPicture(pic)

In Python it would be acceptable to "simulate" an override:
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        if pixmap.isNull():
            return
        self._pixmap = pixmap
        pic = QPicture()
        qp = QPainter(pic)
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
        qp.end()
        self.setPicture(pic)

In C++ this is not really doable, because setPixmap() is not virtual and cannot overridden, and there may also be some issues about ownership and lifespan of the original QPixmap, so you should come up with an appropriate implementation considering the above aspects.

There is a not so elegant hack to this. You can change the parent of the QLabel, enable it, and place it in the right location. I tested this in an oversimplified app.
I dropped a QGroupBox in an empty window. Then I dropped a QLabel with a pixmap in that group box. Disabling the group box does show the image in shades of gray. With the code below (put in the main window constructor) I got the image back in color.
QPoint globalPos = ui->label->mapToGlobal(ui->label->rect().topLeft()); // Store global position of label
ui->groupBox->setEnabled(false);  // Disables the group box making the label "gray"
ui->label->setParent(this);       // Transfers parenthood of the label to main window
ui->label->setEnabled(true);
ui->label->move(globalPos);       // Places the label in proper location
ui->label->show();                // Sets the label visible
ui->label->raise();               // Sets the label are the foreground

The show() and raise() may be necessary or not. In my tests sometimes I needed them, sometimes not. I did not take time to figure out the conditions.
You may also have to tweak with the globalPosition. Essentially, the initial coordinates of the label are measured with respect to the groupBox. The mapToGlobal() function converts those positions to the coordinates of the main window. But depending on the order which you do things, it may give you the wrong number.
So, not very elegant, but it works.

That's not really acceptable. First of all, the global position is not correct, because it doesn't consider the proper relative coordinates (besides, the rect() of a QWidget is always at 0, 0, so it's enough to do mapToGlobal(QPoint())). Then, in case the window layout changes (when resizing, or if any other child causes a layout request), the label won't be repositioned correctly.
